# Azure Authenticated Web Api Error only with POST calls

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

would you help me?
i've created a web api on azure and chose not to allow anonymous requests but to use azure active directory to authenticate the requests. the app beneath has "sign-in and read user profile" permissions set.

if the controller behind the web api accepts GET requests it works, while it gives me the error : "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

before i call the web api i open a iframe on the page (sharepoint page) to implicitly get the token from the web api, which calls the basic GET action below:

```
    [ActionName("Connect")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Connect()
    {
     return base.Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, "OK", new JsonMediaTypeFormatter(), "text/plain");
    }
```

later on i call via jquery another action (POST)...

```
    public IHttpActionResult PostPromote([FromBody] string request)
```

but at this point i receive the 403 (Forbidden) message.

the CORS for my webapi is set in the web.config file:

```
 <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="https://mytenant.sharepoint.com" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true"/>
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
```

if i switch the method to GET it works, as well as (of course) if i permit anonymous requests.

thank you a lot, that's making me crazy.

Comment: I'm not sure the exact problem going on, but wanted to share a [few code samples](https://github.com/azure-samples?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=active+directory+webapi&type=&language=) that implement [similar scenarios](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi).